# how to use group by clause in cursor query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to raise a consolidated report using group by clause on 'helper.TX_NAME' column in the following cursor query.

```
String[] columns = {VivzHelper.UID, helper.TX_NAME, helper.TX_PARTICULARS, helper.TX_AMOUNT, helper.TX_DATE};

Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, 
    columns, 
    helper.TX_ID + "='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '" + datefrom.from_date + "' AND '"  + dateto.to_date + "  ' ", 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null);
```

Comment: "Consolidated" is rather vague. Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: We will leave the date range now. Now, for todays date I have 4 rows. for 3 items being milk- $20,tea-$4,medicine-$12,and again milk $3. I am able to show the 4 rows individually in list view. But actually I want to group item wise and show in 3 rows in list view. The result after grouping should like this: Milk-$23 ($20+$3),tea-$4,medicine-$12.
Pl note: This is for simplecursor adapter for list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get output rows for each combination of date and name, group by these columns:

```
SELECT Date,
       Name,
       SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM TxTable
GROUP BY Date,
         Name
```

In Java, just put the respective parts into the appropriate parameters:

```java
String[] columns = {
    helper.TX_NAME,
    "SUM("+helper.TX_AMOUNT+") AS "+helper.TX_AMOUNT,
    helper.TX_DATE
};
db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE,
         columns,
         helper.TX_ID + "= ? AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?",
         new String[] { name, datefrom.from_date, dateto.to_date },
         helper.TX_NAME + ", " + helper.TX_DATE,
         null, null);
```

Comment: I get error at +","+  in query stating that 'Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String'

Comment: I altered the code accordingly like: 
db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE,
         columns,
         helper.TX_ID + "= ? AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?",
         new String[] { name, datefrom.from_date, dateto.to_date },
         null,
         helper.TX_NAME + ", " + helper.TX_DATE,
         null, null);
But I get exception like:
IllegalArgumentException: HAVING clauses are only permitted when using a groupBy clause

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Cursor c1 = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + VivzHelper.TX_TABLE+ " where '"+ helper.TX_ID + "'='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '" + datefrom.from_date + "' AND '"  + dateto.to_date + "' GROUP BY "+helper.TX_NAME, null);
```

Note : You can use column names instead of " * " in SELECT Query.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+ helper.TX_NAME+","+ helper.TX_PARTICULARS+","+ helper.TX_AMOUNT+","+ helper.TX_DATE +" FROM " + VivzHelper.TX_TABLE+ " where '"+ helper.TX_ID + "'='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '" + datefrom.from_date + "' AND '" + dateto.to_date + "' GROUP BY "+helper.TX_NAME, null);
```

Comment: I used like :
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT helper.TX_NAME, helper.TX_PARTICULARS, helper.TX_AMOUNT, helper.TX_DATE FROM " + VivzHelper.TX_TABLE+ " where '"+ helper.TX_ID + "'='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '" + datefrom.from_date + "' AND '"  + dateto.to_date + "' GROUP BY "+helper.TX_NAME, null);
I get exception like:
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: helper.TX_NAME (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT helper.TX_NAME, helper.TX_PARTICULARS, helper.TX_AMOUNT, helper.TX_DATE FROM transactions where 'txid'='E' AND date BETWEEN

Comment: If still you are getting problem then tell me

Comment: As I am using my code for cursor adapter for list view, I need the groupby 
clause to be included there itself. So accordingly how to include group by for the column 'helper.TX_NAME'.

Comment: Try it :      

Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, helper.TX_ID + "='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '" + datefrom.from_date + "' AND '"  + dateto.to_date + "  ' ", null, helper.TX_NAME, null, null);

Comment: This works but datas retreived in list view is not correct. The range date I 
give is from 16-12-14 to 20-4-14. Total rows entered is 12 for just
 2 items for test purpose. When I run with this code, in list view it shows just 2 rows that belongs to two dates such as 17.12.14 and 20.4.14 and
all other rows are neglected.

Comment: Sorry, the to date is 20.4.15

Comment: Its happens because of group by, just check after remove group by.
Try IT : Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, helper.TX_ID + "='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '" + datefrom.from_date + "' AND '" + dateto.to_date + " ' ", null,null, null, null);

Comment: Yes, this is works for me already. It retrieves all 12 rows and shows the amount for 2 item name individually.  But I want to consolidate the amounts for those 2 items  and show just in 2 rows in the list view for the date range selected. For this I think I should use the 'group by' clause for item name, here being that 'helper.TX_NAME'

Comment: for that you have to use aggregate function for Group By

Comment: We will leave the date range now. Now, for todays date I have 4 rows. for 3 items being milk- $20,tea-$4,medicine-$12,and again milk $3. I am able to show the 4 rows individually in list view. But actually I want to group item wise and show in 3 rows in list view. The result after grouping should like this: Milk-$23 ($20+$3),tea-$4,medicine-$12.

Comment: String[] columns = {VivzHelper.UID, helper.TX_NAME, helper.TX_PARTICULARS, TOTAL(helper.TX_AMOUNT), helper.TX_DATE};


Try it : Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, helper.TX_ID + "='" + name + "'", null, helper.TX_NAME, null, null);

Comment: you can make TOTAL(helper.TX_AMOUNT) with alias name like  TOTAL(helper.TX_AMOUNT) as Price

Comment: Your last query when used gave me the result like: Milk $3,Tea$4,Medicine-$12. It left the first milk $20. Actually it should have been consolidated as one milk and shown as $23.
How to use TOTAL(helper.TX_AMOUNT) in the query.

Comment: In query we can write like : 

"SELECT "+ helper.TX_NAME+","+ helper.TX_PARTICULARS+",TOTAL("+ helper.TX_AMOUNT+") as Price,"+ helper.TX_DATE +" FROM " + VivzHelper.TX_TABLE+ " where '"+ helper.TX_ID + "'='" + name + "'  GROUP BY "+helper.TX_NAME

Comment: If "SELECT" is used I am unable to pass to cursor adaptor for listview.
On 'return c;'
String[] from = new String[]{vivzHelper.TX_NAME,  vivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT, vivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS,vivzHelper.TX_DATE};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textView,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.textView4};
    TextView tf=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.custom_row , c , from , to , 0);
.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outlistview_customshape);
        thislist.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);